# TypeError: expect(...).to.startsWith is not a function - chai and chakram

Tags: javascript, api, automation, chai, chakram

I started writing some automation tests(API)

Now I tried to do to this endpoint:

https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random

so I added into my function

```
expect(response.body.message).to.startsWith('https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/');
```

and at the beginning of the test:

```
    var chakram = require('chakram');
var chai = require('chai');  
chai.use(require('chai-string'))
expect = chai.expect;    // Using Expect style
expect = chakram.expect;
```

Earlier I did not have any problems but with this "expect starts..." after running test I got:
TypeError: expect(...).to.startsWith is not a function - chai and chakram

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] so we can reproduce this? [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/ykl5k7r951) works for me.

Comment: Why does your code assign values to `expect` one right after the other?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't need chai-string you can just do:

```
expect(response.body.message).to.be.a('string').and.satisfy(msg => msg.startsWith('https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/'));
```

Can even do regex in that `satisfy`.

Or better then this, just use `match`:

```
const { escapeRegExp } = require('lodash');
expect(response.body.message).to.be.a('string').and.match(/^https:\/\/images\.dog\.ceo\/breeds\//i);
expect(response.body.message).to.be.a('string').and.match(new RegExp('^' + escapeRegExp('https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/'), 'i')); // this is preferred way so you don't have to worry about escaping, rely on lodash method to escape
```

Answer (score 20):

I am living with following solution without any external dependency

```
expect(result.startsWith("string to match")).to.be.true;
```

Comment: This works, but when the assertion fails, the error message is not very informative.

Comment: @Zhiyong you can customize the message: expect(result.startsWith("string to match"), "Custom message").to.be.true;

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue with Typescript code (Typescript transpiler was outputting an error). It's probably not the exact same issue as yours, but it might help others:

I finally realized that both `chai-string` and `@types/chai-string` packages have to be installed to make it work.

I'm now able to write something like:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
const chai = require('chai');  
chai.use(require('chai-string'));

expect(response.body.message).to.startWith('https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/');
```

which I find more readable and cleaner

Answer (score 1):

It may sounds obvious...but did you install the package? (npm -i chai-string)