# Cypress - how to check if URL contains a number

Tags: javascript, cypress

My URL contain a number that is assigned to a particular item so it might be 1, 2, ..., 999 and so on.

An example:
https://www.test.com/items.889218.html

I want to make assertion like this:

```
cy.url().should('contain', '/items.').and('have', 'number')
```

I tried e.g.:

```
cy.url().invoke('text').should('match', /^[0-9]*$/)
```

or

```
cy.location().should((loc) => {
  expect(loc.pathname).to.contain(/^[0-9]*$/);
});
```

also to provide this kind of path:

```
"/items\.+[0-9]+.html/"
```

But both examples do not work. Any idea how to handle this kind of case?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest regex for your example `https://www.test.com/items.889218.html` would be

```js
cy.url().should('match', /https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items.[0-9]+\.html/)
```

but if you're not concerned about the numbers this should also work

```js
cy.url()
  .should('satisfy', (url) => url.startsWith('https://www.test.com/items.'))
  .and('satisfy', (url) => url.endsWith('.html'))
```

Ref reference [TypeError: expect(...).to.startsWith is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979612/16997707)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

```
cy.location().should((loc) => {
  expect(loc).to.match(/https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items\/(\d+).html/)
})

// or

cy.url().should('match', /https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items\/(\d+).html/)
```

### Explanation:

Your regex query is looking at the end of the string as well because you're using the `$` selector, but your sample URL has `.html` at the end. The choices are, to add `.html` to the pattern, or remove the `$` selector.

```
https://www.test.com/items/[number].html

                                    ^^^^
```

Try:

```
(https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items\/)(\d)+
```

or at least remove the `$` at the end for the end of the string match

```
/https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items\/([0-9]+)/
```

Tested on [regexr](https://regex101.com/r/ZrTqek/1)

### Explanation (for question in comment):

> expected /items.8655.html to include /items./[0-9]+/ FAIL

This pattern includes a `.` between `items.number`. If you need to cover this new variant and the previous one. `(\/|\.)+` will match one or more, `\` and or `.`

```
cy.url().should('match', /https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items(\/|\.)+[0-9]+.html/)
```

Thus above change will match URLs that look like:

```
https://www.test.com/items.8655.html
https://www.test.com/items/8655.html
https://www.test.com/items/.8655.html
```

Comment: Hi, it desnt work. I have something like this in assertion: expected /items.8655.html to include /items./[0-9]+/ FAIL

Comment: The example you just posted is different to the original test URL. You'd need to alter the pattern to include the `.` between items and number. I'll post and example of this, but the best advice I can give for regex is to write it in a testing tool, and then validate your pattern with a few samples. 
https://regex101.com/r/bDyFJf/1
In this example I replaced the `/` with a conditional `(\/|\.)+`

Comment: @Mag
The pattern you provided would pass with a URL like `/items./8655.html`

Comment: Still it dosnt work ;x 
https://www.test.com/items.8655.html to include /items(/|.)+[0-9]+.html/ FAIL My code: /items(/|.)+[0-9]+.html/

Comment: I replaced (/|.) to \. and its looks better, but still failed: test.com/items.8655.html to include /items.+[0-9]+.html/ FAIL

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to invoke the text content of the value yielded from `cy.url`, as it is already a string.

Additionally, your regex is incorrect. It is matching for *only* strings that begin, contain, and ends with numbers.

Fixing the above, you could have something like...

```js
cy.url().should('match', /https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/items\/(\d*)\.html/)
```

Comment: This should work, why is it downvoted?